# How to correctly define types for TS map, reducer, filter etc functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

I'm getting errors in my TS code when I try and pass in the correct type to the built in `.map` and `.filter` functions

when I do: `Object.values(league.games).map((game: Game) => {` I get

```
Argument of type '(game: Game) => { players: { rounds: PlayerRound[]; information: PlayerInformation; hasBeenEliminated: boolean; }[]; complete: boolean; id: string; leagueRound: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown, index: number, array: unknown[]) => { players: { rounds: PlayerRound[]; information: PlayerInformation; hasBeenEliminated: boolean; }[]; complete: boolean; id: string; leagueRound: number; }'.
  Types of parameters 'game' and 'value' are incompatible.
```

But I don't understand how to properly give it the correct type? I'm a bit confused as to what it's asking for

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can type your variables immediately after declaring them. Then a single element in the array will also be of the correct type.

https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-almeida-opq9d?file=/src/index.ts

Answer (score 0):

You may need to provide the generic `T` to `Object.values<T>` so that its return will be of type - `T[]`.

```
values<T>(o: { [s: string]: T } | ArrayLike<T>): T[];
```

#### Solution

```
Object.values<Game>(league.games).map((game) => { ... })

//        values will be Game[] ^       ^ game will be of type Game
```